# Multi-Select template for custom forms

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin3

In my EasyAdmin 3 application I have build a custom form (with Symfony and Doctrine) with a multi-select field. Since it is a custom form I do not get the nice multi-select dropdown theme that EasyAdmin normally provides:

[image]

With earlier EasyAdmin versions it was possible to just add the "select2" classes to the field. But it seems to work different now in EasyAdmin 3. Is there a way to add the multi-select theme of EasyAdmin to a custom form field?

My use case is: I have an AccountEntity which has a relation to a UserEntity and a ServiceEntity. I want to have the possibility to add multiple Accounts for a User with different Services. Since an Account has only one Service I can not use the standard Account Creation Form. I need the Service field to be a multi-select. So my current idea is to built a custom form with Symfony and Doctrine and have my own logic to create the Accounts. Maybe there is a better way to build this functionality with built-in features of EasyAdmin 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer to my problem:

You have to add the following attribute to the form field:

```
data-ea-widget="ea-autocomplete"
```

Also EasyAdmin3 is using https://tom-select.js.org/ instead of Select2 like in the previous versions.